# How to hide the group header in a Kendo grid

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

Is it possible to hide or remove the group header from a kendo grid when grouping is used ?

We are coding with Angular 5.

Comment: I am looking for the same thing... any ideas?

Comment: @Ovi Have posted the answer below, hope not too late.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following CSS to your stylesheet to override default Kendo UI Angular CSS

If you want to hide the header text

```
.k-grid .k-grouping-row p {
    display: none !important;
}
```

If you want to hide the header row

```
.k-grid .k-grouping-row td {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [groupable] attribute can toggle this on and off.

[groupable]="true"

[groupable]="false"

e.g.

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [groupable]="true"
    [group]="state.group" "></kendo-grid>
```

This works with angular 7

Answer (score 0):

Either create a separate css file file for resetting kendo styles and put below code and link in index.html(i applies to all grids you use in your app)

```
.k-grid-header {
  display: none !important;
}
```

---

Or, put this code in the component stylesheet.

```
:host /deep/ .k-grid-header {
  display: none !important;
}
```

This will reset kendo css, also will also override styles if you have a kendo reset linked to your index.html

Answer (score 0):

Using `::ng-deep .k-grouping-header-flex { display: none !important; }` 
::ng-deep accesses the default element of the kendo grids.
if you are still facing issues when applying styles I may also be related to your hierarchy double check if the hierarchy is correctly defined inside the CSS files.